# What is the best way to make Vue pages exists on server?

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application

As I understand SPA load all components entirely. But I want to 1. Load some pages on deamond 2. Make some pages exists on physical server.

For example user open site. `index.html` with main Vue components is loading. User click on `/about` and about page (from /pages/about.html) is loading. But I want to make about not statically page, but also Vue-fied.

Is there any way to switch template and url dynamically without page reloading? For example header for `index.html` and `/about/index.html` would be same?

I know about virtual routing but I do not want to use it.

Comment: As I understand you want to build an SPA but without way that VueJS provides - attaching component to specific route ? 
If is that case, I'm afraid that's not possible.